# How to find earliest and latest dates in a DataFrame in a grouping operation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
url            user    date                  followers
www.test1.com  A       2017-01-04 05:46:00   45
www.test1.com  B       2017-01-03 10:46:00   10
www.test1.com  C       2017-01-05 05:46:00   11
www.test2.com  B       2017-01-03 17:00:00   10
www.test2.com  A       2017-01-04 15:05:00   45
```

For each distinct `url` I need to find the find the total sum of `followers`, the `user` who has the earliest `date`, the number of unique `user` values, the earliest `date` and the latest `date`.

This is what I did so far:

```
val wFirstUser = Window.partitionBy($"url",$"user").orderBy($"date".asc)
val result = df
                .groupBy("url")
                .agg(sum("followers")", countDistinct("user"), min("date"), max("date"))
                .withColumn("rn", row_number.over(wFirstUser)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
```

Expected output:

```
url            first_user    earliest_date         latest_date           sum_followers   distinct_users
www.test1.com  B             2017-01-03 10:46:00   2017-01-05 05:46:00   66              3
www.test2.com  B             2017-01-04 15:05:00.  2017-01-03 17:00:00   55              2
```

But I cannot find the `user` who has the earliest `date` (i.e. `first_user`). Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need a `window` function**. All you need is to *create a struct column to sort it by date to find the minimumm date and corresponding user*  and the rest of the things are as you have done

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val result = df.withColumn("struct", struct("date", "user"))
  .groupBy("url")
  .agg(sum("followers").as("sum_followers"), countDistinct("user").as("distinct_users"), max("date").as("latest_date"), min("struct").as("struct"))
  .select(col("url"), col("struct.user").as("first_user"), col("struct.date").as("earliest_date"), col("latest_date"), col("sum_followers"), col("distinct_users"))
```

which should give you

```
+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
|url          |first_user|earliest_date      |latest_date        |sum_followers|distinct_users|
+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
|www.test1.com|B         |2017-01-03 10:46:00|2017-01-05 05:46:00|66.0         |3             |
|www.test2.com|B         |2017-01-03 17:00:00|2017-01-04 15:05:00|55.0         |2             |
+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------+
```